# Apache Beam Word Count Example via Spark runner and HDFS fails with "Failed to serialize and deserialize property"

Tags: apache-spark, hdfs, apache-beam

I am trying to run the Apache Beam v2.0.0 word count example on Spark v1.6.x (via Yarn v2.7.3) such that it reads from and writes to HDFS (v2.7.3).

Currently, I submit the job via the following command:

```
bin/spark-submit --class org.apache.beam.examples.WordCount \
  --master yarn --deploy-mode cluster \
  test/word-count-beam-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar \
    --inputFile=hdfs://test/input/* \
    --output=hdfs://test/output \
    --runner=SparkRunner --sparkMaster=yarn
```

Unfortunately, the job fails with the following exception:

```
Failed to serialize and deserialize property 'hdfsConfiguration' with value '[Configuration: /usr/hdp/current/hadoop-client/conf/core-site.xml, /usr/hdp/current/hadoop-client/conf/hdfs-site.xml]'
```

Here the full stack trace:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to serialize the pipeline options.
  at org.apache.beam.runners.spark.translation.SparkRuntimeContext.serializePipelineOptions(SparkRuntimeContext.java:58)
  at org.apache.beam.runners.spark.translation.SparkRuntimeContext.<init>(SparkRuntimeContext.java:41)
  at org.apache.beam.runners.spark.translation.EvaluationContext.<init>(EvaluationContext.java:67)
  at org.apache.beam.runners.spark.SparkRunner.run(SparkRunner.java:196)
  at org.apache.beam.runners.spark.SparkRunner.run(SparkRunner.java:85)
  at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.run(Pipeline.java:295)
  at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.run(Pipeline.java:281)
  at at.tmobile.bigdata.examples.WordCount.main(WordCount.java:184)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
  at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$$anon$2.run(ApplicationMaster.scala:561)
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Unexpected IOException (of type java.io.IOException): Failed to serialize and deserialize property 'hdfsConfiguration' with value '[Configuration: /usr/hdp/current/hadoop-client/conf/core-site.xml, /usr/hdp/current/hadoop-client/conf/hdfs-site.xml]'
  at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.fromUnexpectedIOE(JsonMappingException.java:163)
  at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.writeValueAsString(ObjectMapper.java:2342)
  at org.apache.beam.runners.spark.translation.SparkRuntimeContext.serializePipelineOptions(SparkRuntimeContext.java:56)
  ... 12 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to serialize and deserialize property 'hdfsConfiguration' with value '[Configuration: /usr/hdp/current/hadoop-client/conf/core-site.xml, /usr/hdp/current/hadoop-client/conf/hdfs-site.xml]'
  at org.apache.beam.sdk.options.ProxyInvocationHandler$Serializer.ensureSerializable(ProxyInvocationHandler.java:710)
  at org.apache.beam.sdk.options.ProxyInvocationHandler$Serializer.serialize(ProxyInvocationHandler.java:629)
  at org.apache.beam.sdk.options.ProxyInvocationHandler$Serializer.serialize(ProxyInvocationHandler.java:618)
  at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider.serializeValue(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:128)
  at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._configAndWriteValue(ObjectMapper.java:2881)
  at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.writeValueAsString(ObjectMapper.java:2338)
  ... 13 more
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Conflicting property-based creators: already had [constructor for java.util.ArrayList, annotations: [null]], encountered [constructor for java.util.ArrayList, annotations: [null]]
  at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._createAndCache2(DeserializerCache.java:266)
  at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._createAndCacheValueDeserializer(DeserializerCache.java:241)
  at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache.findValueDeserializer(DeserializerCache.java:142)
  at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.findRootValueDeserializer(DeserializationContext.java:394)
  at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._findRootDeserializer(ObjectMapper.java:3169)
  at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:3062)
  at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2175)
  at org.apache.beam.sdk.options.ProxyInvocationHandler$Serializer.ensureSerializable(ProxyInvocationHandler.java:708)
  ... 18 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Conflicting property-based creators: already had [constructor for java.util.ArrayList, annotations: [null]], encountered [constructor for java.util.ArrayList, annotations: [null]]
  at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.impl.CreatorCollector.verifyNonDup(CreatorCollector.java:228)
  at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.impl.CreatorCollector.addPropertyCreator(CreatorCollector.java:168)
  at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BasicDeserializerFactory._handleSingleArgumentConstructor(BasicDeserializerFactory.java:487)
  at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BasicDeserializerFactory._addDeserializerConstructors(BasicDeserializerFactory.java:406)
  at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BasicDeserializerFactory._constructDefaultValueInstantiator(BasicDeserializerFactory.java:325)
  at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BasicDeserializerFactory.findValueInstantiator(BasicDeserializerFactory.java:266)
  at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BasicDeserializerFactory.createCollectionDeserializer(BasicDeserializerFactory.java:851)
  at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._createDeserializer2(DeserializerCache.java:390)
  at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._createDeserializer(DeserializerCache.java:348)
  at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._createAndCache2(DeserializerCache.java:261)
  ... 25 more
```

Does anybody know how to fix this?

Comment: Can you enumerate the classes you get when you execute: java.util.ServiceLoader.load(com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.Module.class)?

Comment: Also, what are all the classes of the values stored in the Hadoop configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem.

The modules loaded in `java.util.ServiceLoader.load(com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.‌​Module.class)` are:

- DefaultScalaModule
- HadoopFileSystemModule
- [ParanamerModule](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-paranamer/blob/master/src/main/java/com/fasterxml/jackson/module/paranamer/ParanamerModule.java)

The problem is with `dfsConfiguration` property of type `ArrayList<Configuration>`.

Exclusion of `paranamer` dependency in `jackson-module-scala` dependency of `spark runner` profile helps:

```
 <profiles>
     <profile>
        <id>spark-runner</id>
        <dependencies>
            ...
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.module</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-module-scala_2.10</artifactId>
                <version>2.8.8</version>
                <scope>runtime</scope>
                <exclusions>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.module</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jackson-module-paranamer</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                </exclusions>
            </dependency>
            ...
        </dependencies>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

[ParanamerModule](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-paranamer/blob/master/src/main/java/com/fasterxml/jackson/module/paranamer/ParanamerModule.java) checks property annotations and fails for `ArrayList` constructors but it is optional.